# What relevance is 1.307 to the series 1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4... + 1/n

Tags: c#, math

I'm currently working my way through the Nakov book, Fundamentals of Computer Programming in C#.  In Chapter 4 question 12 states:

> Write a program that calculates the sum (with the precision of 0.001) of the following sequence: 1 + 1/2 - 1/3 + 1/4 - 1/5 + …

It seemed to me to be a relatively straightforward question.  The series is a diminishing fraction that does not have an asymptote.  Stopping the loop at a certain point due to diminished changes in value meets the precision requirements AFAIC.  However, the solution given in both the Hungarian and English versions of the book makes reference to an obscure (to me) value of 1.307.  As follows:

> Accumulate the sum of the sequence in a variable inside a while-loop (see the chapter "Loops"). At each step compare the old sum with the new sum. If the difference between the two sums Math.Abs(current_sum – old_sum) is less than the required precision (0.001), the calculation should finish because the difference is constantly decreasing and the precision is constantly increasing at each step of the loop. The expected result is 1.307.

Can someone explain what this might mean?

Comment: Header and question body show different sequences

Comment: @SvenRasmussen - I hope that when you are computing the sum you are computing the sum of the positive elements separately from the negative elements and then adding them together in the final step. Otherwise you'll suffer from subtractive cancellation.

Comment: You mean the series with all positive elements. It's the Leibnitz formula for pi: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_%CF%80

Comment: Expected value is pi/4.

Answer (score 1):

Note that header contains "harmonic sequence" that has no limit.

But question body shows alternate sign sequence that converges towards value `2 - ln(2)`

Answer (score 0):

> The expected result is 1.307.

I think they are simply saying what the result of the calculation is, so you can check your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The sequence you've got

> 1 + 1/2 - 1/3 + 1/4 + ...

is the same as the [Alternating Harmonic Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#Alternating_harmonic_series) on Wikipedia, except with the signs from 1/2 onwards flipped:

> 1 - 1/2 + 1/3 - 1/4 + ... = ln 2

and the natural logarithm of 2, ln 2, = 0.693. Hence your 1.307 here = 2 - ln 2.